# sqlalchemy multi-session commit fails silently, how to change INSERT to UPDATE

Tags: python, mysql, session, sqlalchemy

I have a Event model, where external_id is set to be unique.

```
    session1 = create_session()
    session2 = create_session()

    e1 = Event(external_id=1, headline='session1')
    session1.add(e1)
    e2 = Event(external_id=1, headline='session2')
    session2.add(e2)
    session1.commit()
    session2.commit()
    s = create_session()
    e = s.query(Event).filter_by(external_id=1).first()
    print e.headline
```

I am getting output "session1" with no errors, which means session2.commit failed, silently. Ultimately I would like to have choose do I want to overwrite what's in db or not. So if session2.commit() fails, I would like to choose wether to change insert to update for some cases. Anyone can help with this? Thanks.

EDITED:
I found the answer. The way to do it is through a two pass mechanism:
  both session should add/commit row with minimal information (unique key only)
  both sessions should do query and get the row for update
  if we want one session to have priority, make sure we use lock for update for it

Comment: let me rephrase the question: if there are two simultaneous commits adding the same key in two separate sessions, how can I choose one of them as what should go into db.

Comment: I guess it is not possible to make decision when commit. I probably should try to lock the item.

Comment: Okay, Apparently I can do this in two pass:

1. both thread add row with minimal information, maybe unique key only.

2. the important one should use update with lock